# How to hidden value when it doesn't match

Tags: oracle12c

I'm in a trouble like this:

For a following table A with data

```
|ID| |Department| |Name|
 1        IT       JOHN
 3        IT       JOHN
 5        IT       JOHN
 1       SALE      LINH
 3       SALE      LINH 
 2       SALE      LINH
 3      CLERK      MINA
 6      CLERK      MINA 
 4      CLERK      MINA
```

There are some ROLEID, each ROLEID has role corresponding, such as 1 is Manager,2 is leader...

I want to select based on ROLEID, if exist ROLEID = 3, all values has department is IT won't display. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the connection of ROLEID from this table? Also please explain a bit what do you mean by `if exist ROLEID = 3, all values has department is IT won't display`

Comment: [mcve] can be useful to improve your question and get good answers

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including DDL statements for *all* the relevant tables and columns (so we can see where `ROLEID` is stored and how it relates to table `A`), DML statements for yours sample data and your expected output for that sample data.